# .Formula subtracting cell values instead of relative cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set cell *DY3* equal to *a.Address - b.Address* (as in, *CP3 - CB3*), but instead I am getting the actual value of these cells (as in, 53-50).

While the final value would technically be the same, I do not want the result hardcoded.

I thought setting the .Formula property of the desired range equal to the .Address properties would return the relative cells and not the actual values within the cells.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub test()

    Dim Month As Variant
    
    Month = InputBox("Enter current month abbreviation (e.g. Jan)", "Historical/Actual/CE Column Formatting")
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("CI2:CU411")
        Set a = .Find(Month, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Range("BU2:CG411")
        Set b = .Find(Month, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 0)
    End With
    
        Range("DY3").Formula = Range(a.Address) - Range(b.Address)
        
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following:

```
Range("DY3").Formula = "=" & a.Address & "-" & b.Address
```

If you want the addresses to be relative, then:

```
Range("DY3").Formula = "=" & a.Address(False, False) & "-" & b.Address(False, False)
```